# I am looking find dups

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates

I am trying to filter out the dups writing a query in Oracle TOAD SQL. Below is the data I have:

```
Primary          T_ID           C_ID
2039515494      276162453       20028
2176514662      276721971       5508
2176514662      276721972       5508
```

I am looking to have only

```
 Primary          T_ID          C_ID
2176514662      276721971       5508
2176514662      276721972       5508
```

Comment: What's the rule to consider two rows "duplicates"? I can't clearly get it from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the window (analytic) variant of `count` could help you:

```
SELECT primary, t_id, c_id
FROM   (SELECT primary, t_id, c_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY primary, c_id) AS cnt
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

Comment: I don't think you want `t_id` in the partition clause.  Note the sample output has two different values of `t_id`.  (The questioner has not clearly stated what fields they want to consider to define a duplicate.)

Comment: @DaveCosta true 'dat. I misread the data in the given result.

Comment: @DaveCosta and mureinik, Thank you both for your help, I did remove the t_id since I needed to have that as final answer.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you are looking for rows with duplicate 'primary' values;

```
select * from t where primary in 
(select primary from t group by(primary) having count(primary) > 1);
```

This assumes you want to consider both primary and c_id

```
with t1 as (select primary, c_id from t group by(primary, c_id) having count(*) > 1) 
select t.primary, t.t_id, t.c_id from t, t1 where t.c_id = t1.c_id and t.primary = t1.primary;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `exists`, I think:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.primary = t.primary and t2.t_id <> t.t_id);
```

This assumes that `t_id` is unique.  You might want to include `c_id` as well for the comparisons.